Showing object details of a selected object in another UserControl using MVVM
I have a person list filled from the database, two fields (id, name) from the person object are databinded with a radiobutton, now when I click on the radiobutton I'm opening a new UserControl and trying to show all the fields of the selected object in the UserControl in detail.
how can I implement this within mvvm?
Model:
namespace PersonMVVM
 {
class PersonModel
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string PersonAge { get; set; }
    public string PersonAddress { get; set; }
    public string PersonDepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string PersonGroupID { get; set; }
    public string PersonContact { get; set; }
    public string PersonLevelEductationID { get; set; }
    public string PersonDivisionID { get; set; }
}
}

ViewModelBase
namespace PersonMVVM
{
class ViewModelBase: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnpropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = 
 null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
  PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

    }
 }
}

DataRepository
namespace PersonMVVM
 {
class DataRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<PersonModel> GetPersonModels()
    {
        var persons = new List<PersonModel>();
        var Connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MysqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(Connect))
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.Connection = conn;
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT person.id, person.name, person.surname, person.address, person.age, person.contact, department.name AS 'department', groupp.name AS 'group', eductation.lavel, division.name AS 'division' FROM person LEFT JOIN department ON department.id = person.departmentID LEFT JOIN groupp ON groupp.id = person.groupID LEFT JOIN eductation ON eductation.id = person.eductationLavelID LEFT JOIN division ON division.id = person.divisionID";
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                persons.Add(new PersonModel()
                {
                    PersonID = (int)reader["id"],
                    Name = (string)reader["name"],
                    Surname = (string)reader["surname"],
                    PersonAddress = (string)reader["address"],
                    PersonAge = (string)reader["age"],
                    PersonContact = (string)reader["contact"],
                    PersonDepartmentID = (string)reader["department"],
                    PersonGroupID = (string)reader["group"],
                    PersonLevelEductationID = (string)reader["lavel"],
                    PersonDivisionID = (string)reader["division"]
                });
            }
        }
        return persons;
    }
}
}

PersonViewModel
namespace PersonMVVM
 {
   class PersonViewModel: ViewModelBase
   {
    public ObservableCollection<PersonModel> PersonItems { get; }

    private PersonModel _selectedPersonItem;
    public PersonModel SelectedPersonItem
    {
        get => _selectedPersonItem;
        set { _selectedPersonItem = value; OnpropertyChanged(nameof(this.SelectedPersonItem)); }
    }
    private readonly DataRepository dataRepository;
    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        this.PersonItems = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel>();
        this.dataRepository = new DataRepository();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        // Do not make such potentially long-running and blocking calls from the constructor
        IEnumerable<PersonModel> personModels = this.dataRepository.GetPersonModels();
        foreach (PersonModel personModel in personModels)
        {
            this.PersonItems.Add(personModel);
        }
    }
}

}
MainViewModel
namespace PersonMVVM
 {
 class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PersonViewModel PersonViewModel { get; } = new PersonViewModel();
    public NavigationViewModel NavigationViewModel { get; } = new NavigationViewModel();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Can be async if required
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // Do not make such potentially long-running and blocking calls from the constructor
        this.PersonViewModel.Initialize();
    }
}

}
MasterDetailsControl.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="PersonMVVM.MasterDetailsControl"
         x:Name="Root"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PersonMVVM"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <!-- Master view column -->
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <!-- Details view column -->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ItemsSource}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=SelectedDetailsItem}"
         ItemTemplate="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ItemTemplate}" />

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                Content="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=SelectedDetailsItem}"
                ContentTemplate="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=SelectedDetailsItemTemplate}" />
</Grid>

MasterDetailsControl.xaml.cs
namespace PersonMVVM
 {
public partial class MasterDetailsControl : UserControl
{
    public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get => (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(ItemsSource),
      typeof(IList),
      typeof(MasterDetailsControl),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default));

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(ItemTemplate),
      typeof(DataTemplate),
      typeof(MasterDetailsControl),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default));

    public object SelectedDetailsItem
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(SelectedDetailsItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedDetailsItemProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDetailsItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(SelectedDetailsItem),
      typeof(object),
      typeof(MasterDetailsControl),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(object), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public DataTemplate SelectedDetailsItemTemplate
    {
        get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(SelectedDetailsItemTemplateProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedDetailsItemTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDetailsItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(SelectedDetailsItemTemplate),
      typeof(DataTemplate),
      typeof(MasterDetailsControl),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default));

    public MasterDetailsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

}
MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="PersonMVVM.MainWindow"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PersonMVVM"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<local:MasterDetailsControl Grid.Column="0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding PersonViewModel.PersonItems}"
                    SelectedDetailsItem="{Binding PersonViewModel.SelectedPersonItem}">
    <local:MasterDetailsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PersonModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:MasterDetailsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <local:MasterDetailsControl.SelectedDetailsItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PersonModel}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonID}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonAge}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:MasterDetailsControl.SelectedDetailsItemTemplate>
</local:MasterDetailsControl>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
namespace PersonMVVM
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainViewModel MainViewModel;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        this.DataContext = this.MainViewModel;

        InitializeComponent();

        // Initialize the view model classes
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MainViewModel.Initialize();
    }
}
}


You should not wrap the ItemsControl into a ScrollViewer. This produces a different result/behavior You will scroll the ItremsControl and not the items inside the control which can lead to subtle weird behavior). Instead, you must wrap the ItemsPresenter of the ItemsControl. Or better use a ListBox which already does this for you and adds additional performance features that you usually don't want to miss.

Between all the lines I understood that you have a list of PersonModel items that is presented in an ItemsControl. Now you want to display the SelectedItem in a new UserControl to show the details of the selected PersonModel. If this is the case, then why does your UserControl contain another ItemsControl and what is the Mary_cityItems it binds to? If you want to display a single object then how does the ItemsControl relate to your problem?

@BionicCode, ok, thanks for the good advice, does the listbox have a command binding?. I'm trying to double click on a cell and open a new user controller where it will be presented in detail

No it does not have a Comand property. But you can attach event handler to the ListBoxItem or override the container template to replace the ContentPresenter with aButton.

@BionicCode, sorry, corrected, grammatical error, of course PersonItems

I see. But was my understanding correct? You want to display a single PersonModel in your UserControl? You are currently showing a list. The same as in the main control. Taht's why I was asking about the second ItemsControil. Could be more specific please?

And waht is showPageCommand doing? I suggest to provide the related necessary context that helps to understand what you are doing so that we can suggest a solution.,

yes, you understood correctly, in the main control only the ID and Name fields will be displayed, in the second ItemsControil the selected item will be shown in detail (first name, last name, age, address, department)

@BionicCode, ok, sorry, my fault, I'll post the full code now

SO, have you picked the wrong control to display the single item and instead display all? This is confusing. Is this ItemsControl really needed or is just your attempt to display a single item using a list? Can you please show how you load that UserControl (what the Show command is doing). For some reason you don't answer my questions ;)

Ah ok. Thank you.

Just as a note, the fact that PersonModel, the data model, accesses the database on its own is a code smell. Ideally you have a single place in your application where database is accessed.  In an MVVM application this place is somewhere in the application model (not in the view and not in the view model). Usually, the view model class would get the items/data models you want to display from the model and use these items to populate an ObservableCollection. The view model does not know whether these data come from a database or file etc.

You should definitely remove all the database code from the PersonModel.

Oh, as long the code only relevant lines it doesn't matter much if it is long. What matters more is the fragmentation of your posted code. Where is the command implemented, which class? I Suggest to post a complete class structure instead of fragmented parts like properties, next fragment shows the constructor. Instead show the complete class. These fragments lack context. Now I don't know where your latest fragment belongs to. I'm sorry, but I hope you understand my point of view. I don't know anything of your code.

Please consolidate all fragments. I will also post an answer that is not fragmented.

@BionicCode, ok, I'll fix it now and post the full code

As a note, you could save some boilerplate code by using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.

Dear, forgive me for making you worried, I corrected the sections, now is there any understanding from my code?

I've heard a lot about CommunityToolkit.Mvvm, but haven't tried it yet. I will definitely try this template

Yes it's much much better. Now I get an idea how your types are interacting e.g to load the details view. Now I can create an example that directly addresses your scenario.

What you are after is called master-detail view. You can achieve this by using a ContentControl to display the details view.
You would assign the data model for the details view to the ContentControl.Content property and define a DatatTemplate to actually render the view. You assign this template to the ContentControl.Contenttemplate property or define the DataTemplate as implicit so that it will be automatically loaded.
Since loading is triggered by a Button you can pass the details model as command parameter or by binding the ListBox.SelectedItem property to the view model that also defines the ICommand.
Some considerations:

ItemsControl should not be wrapped into a ScrollViewer. Instead wrap the ItemsPresenter of the ItemsControl. This way you properly scroll the items and not the ItemsControl. A ListBox comes with a ScrollViewer by default. ListBox is an extended ItemsControl and adds important perfromance features and properties like `SelectedItem that you usually don't want to miss.
Your PersonModel should not access the database to generate a list of its own. Instead, the view model that owns the PersonViewModel must call the application model to return the PersonModel collection. The model internally uses the database or reads/writes from/to a file or service.
You don't have a 1:1 relationship between a control and view model class. In other words, not every control has its own view model. A view model class represents a particular data context. Multiple controls operate with the same data and therefore the same data context. From your data bindings I can tell that the UserControl has the wrong DataContext set. Additionally, you avoid setting the DataContext explicitly and instead let it be inherited.
The UserControl should not bind its internals directly to the DataContext. Instead, introduce dependency properties that the internal can bind to. Then bind these dependency properties to the actual DataContext. This is especially important if you want to reuse the control in different places or applications. If you don't need this flexibility, you can of course continue to hardcode the dependencies into your custom controls. I was just pointing out that this is not the best practice.
Try to use composition for your view model classes. For example, you can define a MainViewModel that exposes other view models classes like the PersonViewModel or the NavigationViewModel. Then assign the MainViewModel to the DataContext root (e.g. the MainWindow). This is far easier to maintain and adds flexibility. For example, such a structure would allow you to use dependency injection, since the only view model to inject would be the MainViewModel into the MainWindow.
Creating controls, or handling controls in the view model is violating the MVVM design pattern rules.
Performing UI logic like opening or closing views in the view model violates the MVVM design pattern. Such code belongs to the view (e.g. code-behind. For example, to close the window or application you can use common event handlers and the Button.Click event or use routed commands and the Button.Command property.
You don't have to explicitly close resources that implement IDisposable. The using-statement will do that for you. Disposing objects will automatically close them and flush buffers e.g. in case of Stream objects.

To improve the convenience, you could also merge both views into a single control MasterDetailsControl. Maybe that helps you with the integration:
Usage Example
<Window>
  <MasterDetailsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PersonViewModel.PersonItems}"
                        SelectedDetailsItem="{Binding PersonViewModel.SelectedPersonItem}">
    <MasterDetailsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PersonModel}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </MasterDetailsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <MasterDetailsControl.SelectedDetailsItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PersonModel}">
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonID}" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonAge}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </MasterDetailsControl.SelectedDetailsItemTemplate>
  </MasterDetailsControl>
</Window>

MasterDetailsControl.xaml.cs
public partial class MasterDetailsControl : UserControl
{
  public IList ItemsSource
  {
    get => (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(ItemsSource),
    typeof(IList),
    typeof(MasterDetailsControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default));

  public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
  {
    get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty);
    set => SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(ItemTemplate),
    typeof(DataTemplate),
    typeof(MasterDetailsControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default));

  public object SelectedDetailsItem
  {
    get => (object)GetValue(SelectedDetailsItemProperty);
    set => SetValue(SelectedDetailsItemProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDetailsItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(SelectedDetailsItem),
    typeof(object),
    typeof(MasterDetailsControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(object), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

  public DataTemplate SelectedDetailsItemTemplate
  {
    get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(SelectedDetailsItemTemplateProperty);
    set => SetValue(SelectedDetailsItemTemplateProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDetailsItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(SelectedDetailsItemTemplate),
    typeof(DataTemplate),
    typeof(MasterDetailsControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default));

  public MasterDetailsControl()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}

MasterDetailsControl.xaml
<UserControl x:Name="Root">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> <!-- Master view column -->
      <ColumnDefinition /> <!-- Details view column -->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="0"
             ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ItemsSource}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=SelectedDetailsItem}"
             ItemTemplate="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ItemTemplate}" />

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=SelectedDetailsItem}"
                    ContentTemplate="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=SelectedDetailsItemTemplate}" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private readonly MainViewModel mainViewModel;

  public MainWindow()
  {
    this.mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    this.DataContext = this.mainViewModel;

    InitializeComponent();

    // Initialize the view model classes
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Initializing all view models from the loaded event is a significant performnace improvement.
    // Just think about doing all of this work from the constructor 
    // where each view model class instantiates its own classes that 
    // themself create instances from their constructor and initialize 
    // them. It would take "ages" for the construction of the top-level 
    // instance to complete, while the UI remains unresponsive. 
    // You can even call async methods which isn't possible in the 
    // constructor. 
    // Every class must perform expensive/long-running initialization 
    // outside the constructor.
    this.mainViewModel.Initialize();
  }

  // TODO::Implement window close and application close logic.
  // The logic that was originally implemented in the view model class.
  // For example use event handlers or routed events or routed commands.
}

MainViewModel.cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public PersonViewModel PersonViewModel { get; } = new PersonViewModel();
  public NavigationViewModel NavigationViewModel { get; } = new NavigationViewModel();

  // Can be async if required
  public void Initialize()
  {
    // Do not make such potentially long-running and blocking calls from the constructor
    this.PersonViewModel.Initialize();
  }
}

PersonViewModel.cs
class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public ObservableCollection<PersonModel> PersonItems { get; }

  private PersonModel _selectedPersonItem;
  public PersonModel SelectedPersonItem
  {
    get => _selectedPersonItem;
    set { _selectedPersonItem = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.SelectedPersonItem)); }
  }
    
  // The model class to access the database
  private readonly DataRepository dataRepository;

  public PersonViewModel()
  {
    this.PersonItems = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel>();
    this.dataRepository = new DataRepository();
  }

  // Can be async if required
  public void Initialize()
  {
    // Do not make such potentially long-running and blocking calls from the constructor
    IEnumerable<PersonModel> personModels = this.dataRepository.GetPersonModels();
    foreach (PersonModel personModel in personModels)
    {
      this.PersonItems.Add(personModel);
    }
  }
}

NavigationViewModel.cs
class NavigationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ...

   /* 
    * The following code does not belong into a view model class. 
    * This must be handled by the view! For example, in code-behind.
    * You can use event handlers for Button.Click events or routed commands.
    * Then close the Window or the application from there.
    * Handling controls in the view model violates the MVVM design pattern.
    */

  //// Close App
  //public void CloseApp(object obj)
  //{
  //  MainWindow win = obj as MainWindow;
  //  win.Close();
  //}

  //// Close App Command
  //private ICommand _closeCommand;
  //public ICommand CloseAppCommand
  //{
  //  get
  //  {
  //    if (_closeCommand == null)
  //    {
  //      _closeCommand = new RelayCommand(p => CloseApp(p));
  //    }
  //    return _closeCommand;
  //  }
  //}
}

DataRepository.cs
The model class.
Data persistence (database and file I/O or service consumption) always belongs to the application model. And not the view model or data model classes. Aim to have all queries in a single place (to avoid duplicate code).
class DataRepository
{
  public IEnumerable<PersonModel> GetPersonModels()
  {
    var persons = new List<PersonModel>();
    var Connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MysqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(Connect))
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
    {
      conn.Open();
      command.Connection = conn;
      command.CommandText = @"SELECT person.id, person.name, person.surname, person.address, person.age, person.contact department.name AS 'department', group.name AS 'group', eductation.lavel division.name AS 'division' FROM person
        LEFT JOIN department ON department.id = person.departmentID LEFT JOIN group ON group.id = person.groupID LEFT JOIN eductation ON eductation.id = person.eductationLavelID LEFT JOIN division ON division.id = person.divisionID";
      using MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        Person_list.Add(new PersonModel()
        {
          PersonID = (int)reader["id"],
          Name = (string)reader["name"],
          Surname = (string)reader["surname"],
          PersonAge = (int)reader["age"],
          PersonAddress = (string)reader["address"],
          PersonDepartmentID = (string)reader["department"],
          PersonGroupID = (string)reader["group"],
          PersonContact = (string)reader["contact"],
          PersonLevelEductationID = (string)reader["lavel"],
          PersonDivisionID = (string)reader["division"]
        });
      }
    }
  
    // Don't close these IDisposables. The using-block will handle that.
    //reader. Close();
    //conn.Close();

    return persons;
  }
}


There's a lot going on here, and I know the author of the other answer is genuinely trying to help you, but I think things are getting overcomplicated and maybe sidetracked by issues that really aren't core to your problem, so after lookking at your code, let me take a fresh crack at this by breaking it down into smaller problems, going one level at a time.
Model
In the model layer you have PersonModel which looks like it's the data defining a single person, but it also fetches a list of person objects from a database. This should be broken out into 2 classes. PersonModel itself should represent a single person, so you don't want to put the Get() method there. I suggest a second class, PersonService for retrieving that data, where that Get method should live. Alternatively, you could make the Get() method static. Either way it should not be an instance member of the PersonModel class because - think about it like real world objects. A person wouldn't be providing a list of all the other people, right? That would come from somewhere else - a filing cabinet or something. So retrieval should be in a different class/object - a service or data source - from the thing being retrieved. Like this:
public class PersonService
{
    // Sidenote - this can be a simple array, you'll see why in a minute
    public static PersonModel[] Get()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class PersonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    // etc.
}

View Model
Next is your view model layer where you have a PersonViewModel. Same problem. Based on how you name it, I'd think PersonViewModel is a single person, but you give it a PersonItems member which seems to contain all the pepole. So you have nothing representing a single person. Again, what you ought to do is separate this into a PersonViewModel which corresponds to a single PersonModel, and then some other view model that fetches the data from the model and holds the collection of all the PersonViewModels, which I'll call TeamViewModel for fun:
public class TeamViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public TeamViewModel()
    {
        var personModels = PersonService.Get();
        this.PersonItems = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>(
            personModels.Select(p => new PersonViewModel(p)));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> PersonItems { get; }

    #region PersonViewModel SelectedPerson property
    private PersonViewModel _SelectedPerson;
    public PersonViewModel SelectedPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedPerson == value)
                return;
            _SelectedPerson = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

public class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    PersonModel _data;

    public PersonViewModel(PersonModel data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    #if DEBUG
    // For XAML designer only
    public PersonViewModel()
    {
    }
    #endif

    #region string Name property
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _data?.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_data.Name == value)
                return;
            _data.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region string Surname property
    public string Surname
    {
        get
        {
            return _data?.Surname;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_data.Surname == value)
                return;
            _data.Surname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    //
    // Other property wrappers for PersonModel
    // ...
    //
}

Let's take a pause here and make sure we understand what's going on. There's no UI yet. All of this code is abstract and knows nothing about WPF, RadioButton's, or GUIs at all. Forget about views, or navigation, or how the app window gets closed. Just focus on the basic logic you need to perform and what objects you need to create to do it.
You have a bunch of pepole (PersonModels). You have a way of fetching them (PersonService). You have a view model wrapping the data for a single person (PersonViewModel). You have a view model representing the whole team of people (TeamViewModel). The team view model holds the list of all the PersonViewModels and tracks the currently selected one.
That's all the C# we're gonna need.
View
So now let's turn to the final layer - view. No offense, but I'm gonna throw out what you did and start over. I try not to do that, but I think in this case the problem will make much more sense if we just start from scratch.
Your view, essentially, will be a list of people on one side of the window, and in the other, the details about the selected person. This is what's called "master-detail" (or "list-detail" if you want to be more precise):
<!-- UserControl boilerplate omitted -->
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:TeamViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonItems}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
             SelectionMode="Single"
             Grid.Column="0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>       

    <local:PersonView DataContext="{Binding SelectedPerson}" 
                      Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>

To explain everything in English -
The TeamViewModel is the data context for this UserControl. The ListBox gets its items from the PersonItems member. The ListBox also tracks the SelectedPerson - the GUI will update this property when the user changes the selection by clicking on the item. The item template just displays the name.
The detail view is the second column, which is a PersonView showing the details of a single PersonViewModel (which, again, encapsulates a single PersonModel). By binding its DataContext to SelectedPerson, the view will automatically update to show the details of the currently selected person whenever it changes. This is the power of data binding - one view model, two totally independent views.
For PersonView itself, you don't want another items control or list - you only want the details for just the one person:
<d:UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:PersonViewModel />
</d:UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
    <TextBlock>Name:</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding Name}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Surname:</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.Row="1" 
               Text="{Binding Surname}" />

    <!-- etc. -->
</Grid>

So you see, you don't need any buttons or commands. You don't need any extensive code-behind. Just let WPF's built-in controls do the heavy lifting for you and otherwise rely on using Bindings to make the connections. When you're more comfortable with things, then you can customize them, but you should become much more familiar with MVVM architectural patterns and data binding before trying to do anything more elaborate.
Speaking of which, I'm suggesting you use ListBox instead of ItemsControl because ItemsControl is a very low-level, barebones control that requires quite a bit of extra work to get it to do anything useful, which ListBox gives you built-in. Also, using a collection of RadioButtons is going to be tricky here because you would need a way to track and update every RadioButton's check state when the selection changess. (And RadioButtons can be onery with data binding sometimes - long, long story there). So I'll just have to ask you to trust me that a simple list of people in a list box is your best choice at the moment until you're more comfortable with the basics.
I hope you try this and understand this simplified architecture. If not please let me know in the comments. Otherwise, once you get this working at a prototype level you'll no doubt have additional questions and should post them, but hopefully they will be much more focused problems.
